# completion bool successful not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, boolean, xcode5

i'm working on an app with animation in the second view controller. after the animation finishes i'm trying to automatically segue to the next view controller. i have the segue in

completion:^(BOOL successful){...

but it is not working. I then tried a simple NSLog@"... but that didn't work either. I'm guessing the problem is the BOOL not completing or registering as successful. The animation I have happens and finishes...but the completion BOOL is not carried out. Please help.

from the .m file of secondViewController...

```
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedImage;

@end

@implementation secondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self moveUp:nil finished:nil context:nil];
}
- (void)moveUp:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:1.0
 options:      (UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveDown:finished:context:)];
                     self.animatedImage.center = CGPointMake(160, 304);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Move up done");

                 }];


}

- (void)moveDown:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:1.5
           options:  (UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveUp:finished:context:)];
                     self.animatedImage.center = CGPointMake(160, 775);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backHome" sender:self];
                 }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more of code? As example the part where you create the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code following will be nice and readable.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; //Invoke super method
    [self doAnimation];
}

- (void)doAnimation{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     self.animatedImage.center = CGPointMake(160, 304);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                          delay:1.5
                                        options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                                     animations:^{
                                           self.animatedImage.center = CGPointMake(160, 775);
                                     }
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backHome" sender:self];
                                     }
                   ];}

    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for this! i tried it an the good news is the completion block is working - however the UIImageView is no longer animating. it just stays still for a few seconds then the completion kicks in. any thoughts?

Comment: digging a little deeper i've discovered it's just the movement of the first animation that is not occurring. in other words the delay takes place, the CGPointMake is skipped, the next duration takes place and the 2nd CGPointMake happens. Any idea why the first CGPointMake is being skipped?

Comment: figured it out...unchecked "use auto layout" in file inspector. working perfect now.

Comment: Congratulations! @user3294722 I'm just on the line. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're combining old-style and block-based animations. Don't do that.

Removing

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:...];
```

will probably fix things. Put the completion logic in the completion block instead.

Comment: thanks. i removed those two and the completion:^(BOOL finished){ NSLog(@"Move up done"); worked but the image no longer animated. also, sorry but what do you mean by putting the completion logic in the completion block?